# Missing border for TableView columnHeader - JavaFX

Tags: java, css, javafx, tableview

I am trying to hide box-border for tableView. When I hide that border then border for left side of columnHeader is missing.

Here is my css file:

```
.table-row-cell:empty {
    -fx-background-color: lightyellow;
}

.table-row-cell:empty .table-cell {
    -fx-border-width: 0px;
}

.table-view{
    -fx-focus-color: transparent; 
    -fx-box-border: transparent
}
```

Here is image showing what I mean:

[image]